# UniswapV3: Quoter contract function quoteExactOutputSingle throws unexpected error

Tags: web3.py, uniswap

I have again a problem with the quoteExactOutputSingle function of the quoter contract of uniswap v3. This throws in some cases an unexpected error and I really can't explain why....

Here is the Web3 Python Code:

```
            input_token_address = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2" //weth
            output_token_address = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7" //usdt
            input_token_decimals = 18
            output_token_decimals = 6
            output_token_amount = 1000
            pool_fee = 1.0
            pool_fee = pool_fee * (10 ** 4)
            output_token_amount = output_token_amount * (10 ** output_token_decimals)
            quoter_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=w3.toChecksumAddress("0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6"), abi=quoter_abi)

            amount_in = quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactOutputSingle(input_token_address, output_token_address, int(pool_fee), int(output_token_amount), 0).call()
            amount_in = amount_in / (10 ** input_token_decimals)
```

The code works fine with the weth/usdt pool with 0.05% and with the weth/usdt pool with 0.3%, but with the weth/usdt pool with 1.0% suddenly this error occurs:

...
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3_utils\method_formatters.py", line 566, in raise_solidity_error_on_revert
raise ContractLogicError(response['error']['message'])
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: Unexpected error

I do not understand the problem, appreciate any help!